# Setup Zend Eclipse PDT 3.2.0 (All-In-One) with Ubuntu 14.04 Apache2+PHP5

Tags: php, debugging, zend-framework, ubuntu-14.04, php-5.5

I have a problem with the Zend Eclipse PDT 3.8. (All-in-one) configuration under Ubuntu 14.04:

When I create a new "Local PHP Project", and I want to set up my local running apache2 server for Debugging, i got asked for the Apache2 Config Files after choosing File->New Local PHP Project -> Add Server -> Local Apache HTTP Server), but under new Ubuntu 14.04 Apache2+PHP5 there is no httpd.conf file under /etc/apache2 (or the whole system)

I spent one night for setting up a PHP debugging environment with Ubuntu 14.04. LTS
1.) I set up VirtualBox for Windows with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
2.) I got Apache2 + PHP5 working with the phpinfo() Message:

```
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.5.0. Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

with Zend Debugger v8.0.0 Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.3. Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

I got the Information that i should select "Generic PHP Server" but the debugging is not working. Maybe can someone explain me that steps for the Generic PHP Server? Or is there a different way, now that httpd.conf is not available anymoer?

Comment: Not sure if this will help you (I don't use Eclipse), but on Ubuntu the main Apache config file is at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: Hey Tim, thx but when i point Eclipse to /etc/apache2 it says "Installation Directory does not contain Apache HTTP Server configuration". I think it is because httpd.conf is not available anymore